# Trouble with metamethods

Tags: lua

i wanted to rewrite this code

```
local tb = {}


local meta = {}

function tb.new(b)
local super = {}
super.b = b

setmetatable(super,meta)

return super
end

function tb.add(s1,s2)

return s1.b+s2.b

end

meta.__concat = tb.add

f= tb.new(3)
t= tb.new(4)

print(f..t)
```

in `tb = setmetable({},(metamethod)` style and i came up with this

```
 local tb = setmetatable({},{__concat = function(a,b)

return a+b
end
})

function ins(a)

tb.a = a

return tb.a

end

print(ins(2)..ins(3))
```

i want to know why its not working , i admit i got no idea what im doing and how many words does this post need ;-;

Comment: You are concatenating two numbers into string.  What have you expected instead?  To invoke `__concat` metamethod you should concatenate objects.

Comment: i expected them to add also is ```tb.2``` and ```tb.3```  not an object?

Comment: `tb.a` is a field inside object, this field contains a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(ins(2)..ins(3))
```

resolves to

```
print( 2 .. 3)
```

which resolves to

```
print("2" .. "3")
```

which resolves to

```
print("23")
```

which outputs `23`

Both numbers are implicitly converted to their string representation, then they are concatenated to a single string `"23"`

From the [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: 3.4.6 Concatenation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.6):

> The string concatenation operator in Lua is denoted by two dots
> ('..'). **If both operands are strings or numbers, then the numbers are
> converted to strings** in a non-specified format (see §3.4.3).
> Otherwise, the __concat metamethod is called (see §2.4).

Your first snippet concatenates two tables while your second snippet concatenates two numbers. So in the second case the `__concat` metamethod is never invoked.

Just use `print(ins(2) + ins(3))` if you want to add those two numbers. I don't see why you should replace simple arithmetic operators. That just adds unnecessary confusion.

You would have to concatenate `tb` with something to invoke your `__concat`, not its fields.

Comment: indeed no need to replace simple operators i just wanted to rewrite the first example in ```setmetatable = ({}.metamethod)``` style. so if i want to invoke ```__concat``` do i concatenate ```tb``` with another table?, thnx 4 the answer

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you want this.

```
function tb(b)
    return setmetatable({b = b},{__concat = function(s1,s2)
        return s1.b + s2.b
    end})
end

print(tb(3)..tb(4))
```

Comment: ya i wanted something like this.Thanks for the answer

Comment: i got a question in this part ```return setmetatable({b = b}```  the field ```b = b``` belongs to which table? tb? but its a function

Comment: It's just an anonymous table